# How do you translate this into SQL Server 2008 statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I'm not sure how to translate this from Access to SQL. We are currently using SQL Server 2008. I am trying to migrate Access reports into SQL views.

```
SELECT 
  First(IIf(IsNull([dbo_CUST_ADDRESS]![STATE]),IIf(IsNull([dbo_CUSTOMER]![BILL_TO_STATE]),[dbo_CUSTOMER]![STATE],[dbo_CUSTOMER]![BILL_TO_STATE]),[dbo_CUST_ADDRESS]![STATE])) AS STATE
  , dbo_RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID
  , dbo_RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_DATE
  , dbo_RECEIVABLE.CUSTOMER_ID
  , First(IIf(IsNull([dbo_CUST_ADDRESS]![NAME]),IIf(IsNull([dbo_CUSTOMER]![BILL_TO_NAME]),[dbo_CUSTOMER]![NAME],[dbo_CUSTOMER]![BILL_TO_NAME]),[dbo_CUST_ADDRESS]![NAME])) AS COMPANY
  , Sum(IIf([dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE]![GL_ACCOUNT_ID]='4005-008',0,[dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE]![AMOUNT])) AS Inv_Total_Amt
  , Sum(IIf([dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE]![REFERENCE]<>"LA-COUNTY" And [dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE]![REFERENCE]<>"FREIGHT" And [dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE]![GL_ACCOUNT_ID]<>'4005-008',[dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE]![AMOUNT],0)) AS Subtotal
  , Sum(IIf([dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE]![REFERENCE]="LA-COUNTY",[dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE]![AMOUNT],0)) AS TAX
  , Sum(IIf([dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE]![REFERENCE]="FREIGHT",[dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE]![AMOUNT],0)) AS Freight
  , dbo_RECEIVABLE.SALESREP_ID    
FROM (((dbo_RECEIVABLE RIGHT JOIN dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE ON dbo_RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID = dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE.INVOICE_ID) LEFT JOIN dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER ON dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID = dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID) LEFT JOIN dbo_CUST_ADDRESS ON (dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo_CUST_ADDRESS.CUSTOMER_ID) AND (dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO = dbo_CUST_ADDRESS.ADDR_NO)) LEFT JOIN dbo_CUSTOMER ON dbo_RECEIVABLE.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo_CUSTOMER.ID    
GROUP BY 
  dbo_RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID
  , dbo_RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_DATE
  , dbo_RECEIVABLE.CUSTOMER_ID
  , dbo_RECEIVABLE.SALESREP_ID    
ORDER BY 
  First(IIf(IsNull([dbo_CUST_ADDRESS]![STATE]),IIf(IsNull([dbo_CUSTOMER]![BILL_TO_STATE]),[dbo_CUSTOMER]![STATE],[dbo_CUSTOMER]![BILL_TO_STATE]),[dbo_CUST_ADDRESS]![STATE]))
  , dbo_RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID;
```

This is what I created on 10/21/15. I changed the WHERE to look for an invoice number to test it and added nesting CASEs. It shows 2 lines for that invoice and isn't grouping them into 1.

SELECT
                      (SELECT TOP 1 CASE 
                            WHEN CUST_ADDRESS.STATE IS NULL  THEN 
                            CASE WHEN CUSTOMER.BILL_TO_STATE IS NULL THEN CUSTOMER.STATE
                            ELSE CUSTOMER.BILL_TO_STATE
                          END
                      ELSE CUST_ADDRESS.STATE
                      END
                      FROM         dbo.RECEIVABLE RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.RECEIVABLE_LINE ON dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID = dbo.RECEIVABLE_LINE.INVOICE_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER ON dbo.RECEIVABLE_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID = dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CUST_ADDRESS ON dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.CUSTOMER_ID AND 
                      dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO = dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.ADDR_NO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CUSTOMER ON dbo.RECEIVABLE.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo.CUSTOMER.ID
                      WHERE dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID = 'iv184546') AS STATE,
                      dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID, dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_DATE, dbo.RECEIVABLE.POSTING_DATE, dbo.RECEIVABLE.CUSTOMER_ID, 
                      (SELECT TOP 1 CASE
                            WHEN dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.NAME IS NULL THEN dbo.CUSTOMER.NAME
                            ELSE dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.NAME
                            END
                            FROM         dbo.RECEIVABLE RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.RECEIVABLE_LINE ON dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID = dbo.RECEIVABLE_LINE.INVOICE_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER ON dbo.RECEIVABLE_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID = dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CUST_ADDRESS ON dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.CUSTOMER_ID AND 
                      dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO = dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.ADDR_NO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CUSTOMER ON dbo.RECEIVABLE.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo.CUSTOMER.ID
                            WHERE dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID = 'iv184546') AS COMPANY, 
                    SUM(CASE WHEN RECEIVABLE_LINE.GL_ACCOUNT_ID = '4005-008' THEN 0 ELSE RECEIVABLE_LINE.AMOUNT END) 
                      AS Inv_Total_Amt, SUM(CASE WHEN RECEIVABLE_LINE.REFERENCE <> 'LA-COUNTY' AND RECEIVABLE_LINE.REFERENCE <> 'FREIGHT' AND 
                      RECEIVABLE_LINE.GL_ACCOUNT_ID <> '4005-008' THEN RECEIVABLE_LINE.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Subtotal, 
                      SUM(CASE WHEN RECEIVABLE_LINE.REFERENCE = 'LA-COUNTY' THEN RECEIVABLE_LINE.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS TAX, 
                      SUM(CASE WHEN RECEIVABLE_LINE.REFERENCE = 'FREIGHT' THEN RECEIVABLE_LINE.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Freight, dbo.RECEIVABLE.SALESREP_ID

FROM         dbo.RECEIVABLE RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.RECEIVABLE_LINE ON dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID = dbo.RECEIVABLE_LINE.INVOICE_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER ON dbo.RECEIVABLE_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID = dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CUST_ADDRESS ON dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.CUSTOMER_ID AND 
                      dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO = dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.ADDR_NO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CUSTOMER ON dbo.RECEIVABLE.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo.CUSTOMER.ID
WHERE dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID = 'iv184546'
GROUP BY                CASE 
                            WHEN CUST_ADDRESS.STATE IS NULL  THEN 
                            CASE WHEN CUSTOMER.BILL_TO_STATE IS NULL THEN CUSTOMER.STATE
                            ELSE CUSTOMER.BILL_TO_STATE
                          END
                      ELSE CUST_ADDRESS.STATE
                      END,
                      dbo.CUSTOMER.NAME, dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID, 
                      dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_DATE, dbo.RECEIVABLE.POSTING_DATE, dbo.RECEIVABLE.CUSTOMER_ID, dbo.RECEIVABLE.SALESREP_ID, 
                        CASE
                            WHEN dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.NAME IS NULL THEN dbo.CUSTOMER.NAME
                            ELSE dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.NAME
                            END
ORDER BY dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID, dbo.RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_DATE;

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but your query is pretty messy. It would probably be easier to get a good answer if you also explain the relationships and your desired output with some sample data. That would let us rewrite the query, and may give you a performance boost, instead of asking someone to translate nested `IIF` logic...

Comment: As @Erik said, please add some details concerning the definitions of the source tables, sample data for them, and desired output.

Comment: Instead of `IIF` use [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). Instead of `First` use `MIN` or `MAX`. The rest can remain as it is. It would not be optimal, but it would produce same result as original query. Normally you'd rewrite the query in such a way, that you don't need `First`.

Comment: FIRST is not the same as MIN.  FIRST in Access returns the first inserted row; you may be able to mimic that using the ROW_NUMBER functionality, assuming you have a monotonically increasing column.

Comment: @MaxVernon, Yes, [`First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177902(v=office.12).aspx) is not the same as `MIN`, but... "They simply return the value of a specified field in the first or last record, respectively, of the result set returned by a query. Because records are usually returned in no particular order (unless the query includes an ORDER BY clause), **the records returned by these functions will be arbitrary**." In this query ordering itself is done by the result of the `First`. If this query is correct, then all values that `First` chooses from must be identical.

Comment: I'm not too sure on how to add stuff to this yet. I am trying to get tax information from invoices. The CUST_ADDRESS.STATE should be used as the result of the query. If it is NULL, then the CUSTOMER.BILL_TO_ADDRESS.STATE.  if that is NULL, then the CUSTOMER.STATE.

Comment: If that is NULL, then the CUSTOMER.STATE. If I don't do FIRST, it shows 3 lines. 1 for CA (Subtotal) and 2 for TX (Tax and Freight). @Erik I only want it to show for CA and grouped into 1 line with CA as the STATE. This report is also run for TX and WA.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of rewriting the whole query, I'll give you some hints of how to do it:

- `IIf(condition, a, b)` becomes: `CASE WHEN condition THEN a ELSE b END`
- `IsNull(x)` becomes: `x IS NULL`
- The combined `IIf(IsNull(x), y, x))` can then be written as:
  `CASE WHEN x IS NULL THEN y ELSE x END` and simplified further to `COALESCE(x, y)`.
- The table-column expressions: `[tab]![col]` becomes: `[tab].[col]` and if the names are not reserved, this is more readable: `tab.col`
- Use single quotes (and **not double quotes**) for string literals. Eg, replace `"FREIGHT"` with `'FREIGHT'`. Double quotes are used in standard SQL (and in SQL Server, besides brackets) for quoting table and columns' names and aliases, not for literals.
- The parentheses in the `FROM` clause can be safely removed. SQL Server's parser is happy with or without them.
- Additionally, readability will increase if you use aliases for tables:

  ```
  FROM (((dbo_RECEIVABLE RIGHT JOIN dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE ON dbo_RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID = dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE.INVOICE_ID) LEFT JOIN dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER ON dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID = dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID) LEFT JOIN dbo_CUST_ADDRESS ON (dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo_CUST_ADDRESS.CUSTOMER_ID) AND (dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO = dbo_CUST_ADDRESS.ADDR_NO)) LEFT JOIN dbo_CUSTOMER ON dbo_RECEIVABLE.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo_CUSTOMER.ID
  ```

  becomes:

  ```
  FROM dbo_RECEIVABLE 
    RIGHT JOIN dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE 
      ON  dbo_RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_ID = dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE.INVOICE_ID
    LEFT JOIN dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER 
      ON  dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID = dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID
    LEFT JOIN dbo_CUST_ADDRESS 
      ON  dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo_CUST_ADDRESS.CUSTOMER_ID 
      AND dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO = dbo_CUST_ADDRESS.ADDR_NO
    LEFT JOIN dbo_CUSTOMER 
      ON  dbo_RECEIVABLE.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo_CUSTOMER.ID
  ```

  and then:

  ```
  FROM dbo_RECEIVABLE AS rec
    RIGHT JOIN dbo_RECEIVABLE_LINE AS line
      ON  rec.INVOICE_ID = line.INVOICE_ID
    LEFT JOIN dbo_CUSTOMER_ORDER AS ord
      ON  line.CUST_ORDER_ID = ord.ID
    LEFT JOIN dbo_CUST_ADDRESS AS addr
      ON  ord.CUSTOMER_ID = addr.CUSTOMER_ID 
      AND ord.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO = addr.ADDR_NO
    LEFT JOIN dbo_CUSTOMER AS cust
      ON  rec.CUSTOMER_ID = cust.ID
  ```

  adjusting accordingly all the references in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.
- In `ORDER BY` you can use columns included or aliases defined in the `SELECT` list. No need to repeat complicated expressions or table aliases:

  ```
  ORDER BY STATE, INVOICE_ID; ;
  ```
- By the way, that `RIGHT JOIN` doesn't look right. Especially since the `GROUP BY` is based on the nullable side columns (`dbo_RECEIVABLE` table). It should probably be `INNER` or `LEFT JOIN`.
- the `First()` function is the most difficult part. You could replace it with `MIN()` or `MAX()` but you may not get the same results back and it may not be possible to use this trick in all queries, only those with `GROUP BY`.
  The equivalent would be quite complicated, using either `ROW_NUMBER()` and altering the structure of the whole query (wrapping it in a derived table or a CTE and moving the `GROUP BY` from the internal level to the external one). In 2012+ versions, the `FIRST_VALUE()` function might be used, too.

Comment: I will try this. I created something yesterday too, but it isn't working properly. @ypercube